# Scroll to specific div in child compont?

Tags: angular

**Parent.component.html**

```
<div class="page-container topspaces vh-70">
    <piqet-angular-breadcrumbs [activatedPath]="activatedRoute" [projectName]="projectName"></piqet-angular-breadcrumbs>
    <div class="page-content responsive-height" id="post6" [ngClass]="{'disabled-project' : !isEdit}">
        <div class="container-fluid h-100">
            <div class="mainDiv d-flex margin-top-10">
                <div class="sideMenu">
                    <piqet-angular-project-details-sidebar (projectNameEvent)="handleData($event)"
                        [sidebarTour]="[sidebarTour]"></piqet-angular-project-details-sidebar>
                </div>
                <div class="contentDiv" id="scrollableDiv">
                    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

## in that router outlet load child componet

```
 <div class="row generateBtn" id="post8">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <button type="submit" (click)="onGenerate()" class="modelBtn purpleBtnHoverEffect">Generate</button>
                </div>
            </div>
<div class="mainChatDiv borderTopBottom" #chartContainer
    *ngIf="(isBarChartSelected && generated && componentItemsArray.length > 0) || (!isBarChartSelected && generated && componentItemsArray.length > 0)">
    <div class="canvas spiderChartDesign" *ngIf="componentItemsArray.length > 0 && setChartTypeId == 3">
        <canvas baseChart [datasets]="spiderChartData" height="500" width="1030" [type]="'radar'"
            [labels]="spiderChartLabels" [options]="spiderChartOptions" [plugins]="doughnutChartPlugins">
        </canvas>
    </div>
    <div id="goTOSpiderChat" class="canvas" *ngIf="componentItemsArray.length > 0 && setChartTypeId == 2">
        <div class="topIndicatorName">{{topIndicatorName}}</div>
        <div class="barChartDesign">
            <canvas baseChart [datasets]="barChartData" [labels]="mbarChartLabels" [options]="barChartOptions"
                class="setHeigthWidth" [type]="'bar'"></canvas>
        </div>
        <!-- <kendo-chart>
            <kendo-chart-category-axis>
                <kendo-chart-category-axis-item [categories]="categories"></kendo-chart-category-axis-item>
            </kendo-chart-category-axis>
            <kendo-chart-series>
                <ng-container *ngFor="let segment of segments; let i = index">
                    <kendo-chart-series-item type="column" [stack]="{ type: '100%' }" [data]="segment.percentages"
                        [name]="segment.name" [color]="segmentColors[i]">
                        <kendo-chart-series-item-tooltip>
                            <ng-template let-value="value">
                                <span class="custom-tooltip">{{ value | number: '1.2-2' }} %</span>
                            </ng-template>
                        </kendo-chart-series-item-tooltip>
                    </kendo-chart-series-item>
                </ng-container>
            </kendo-chart-series>
        </kendo-chart> -->
    </div>
</div>
```

when click onGenerate button scroll to #chartContainer div in angular

I did

**TS file **

```
  @ViewChildren('chartContainer') chartContainers!: QueryList<ElementRef>;

 ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.chartContainers.changes.subscribe(() => {
      this.chartContainers.forEach(container => {
        const spiderElement = this.document.getElementById('goTOSpiderChat')
        debugger
        if (spiderElement) {
          spiderElement.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start', inline: 'nearest' });
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

its working but when click button scroll first parent componet after child componet

I except not scroll parent component , scroll only child component

Comment: please share a simple stackblitz with the issue replicated and details on expected output from the stackblitz, for debugging!